# Lightning Dashboard component size keeps increasing over time

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am using the Standard Dashboard component to view on the Home Page App.
The vertical size of the Dashboard component keeps growing all time. This happens both in the edit canvas, as well as from User POV.

See some images, taken after several seconds.
First image
[image]

after 10 seconds
[image]

after another 10 seconds
[image]

Any idea why is this happening?
How to stop this?

Note: I found out that if I give a 'Max Height' to the component, it increases up to that height, only than it stops.

I don't think this is how it should behave though.